# Vert.x application quickstart

Tags: java, object-oriented, functional-programming, asynchronous

I have created [this repository](https://github.com/thokari/epages-app-kickstart) that implements [this OAuth2 flow](https://developer.epages.com/apps/install-app.html#docs). I wanted to use Java and create a minimal implementation of this flow with these goals in mind:

1. Develop unit and integration tests in a straightforward way
2. No heavy framework usage, mostly "explicit" code
3. Have some kind of pattern for domain classes, and a straightforward way to validate request data

I would like to get some feedback on these points specifically:

1. No usage of any ORM framework, writing custom code to build SQL queries, for example:

   [The last 4 methods of class *Installation*](https://github.com/thokari/epages-app-kickstart/blob/master/src/main/java/de/thokari/epages/app/model/Installation.java#L47-L74)

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   public String getInsertQuery() {
       return String.format("INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES %s", TABLE_NAME, getColumnNames(), getParameterPart());
   }


   @JsonIgnore
   public String getParameterPart() {
       return this.toJsonObject().stream()
           .filter(it -> it.getValue() != null)
           .map(it -> "?")
           .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));
   }


   @JsonIgnore
   public String getColumnNames() {
       return this.toJsonObject().stream()
           .filter(it -> it.getValue() != null)
           .map(it -> it.getKey())
           .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));
   }


   @JsonIgnore
   public JsonArray getInsertQueryParams() {
       return new JsonArray(
           this.toJsonObject().stream()
               .filter(it -> it.getValue() != null)
               .map(it -> it.getValue())
               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
   }
   ```
2. Mixing Futures with callbacks, especially in this one most important and problematic method: [`AppInstallationVerticle::handleInstallationRequest()`](https://github.com/thokari/epages-app-kickstart/blob/master/src/main/java/de/thokari/epages/app/AppInstallationVerticle.java#L41-L94)

   ```
   private Handler<Message<JsonObject>> handleInstallationRequest(String clientId, String clientSecret) {
       return message -> {
           InstallationRequest event = Model.fromJsonObject(message.body(), InstallationRequest.class);


           if (!event.hasValidSignature(clientSecret)) {
               String errorMsg = "Received installation request with invalid signature: " + event.toString();
               LOG.error(errorMsg);
               message.fail(400, errorMsg);
           } else {


               LOG.info("received installation event " + event.toString());


               OAuth2ClientOptions credentials = new OAuth2ClientOptions()
                   .setClientID(clientId).setClientSecret(clientSecret)
                   .setSite(event.apiUrl).setTokenPath(event.tokenPath);


               requestOAuth2Token(credentials, event.code, event.returnUrl).setHandler(tokenResponse -> {


                   if (tokenResponse.failed()) {
                       String errorMsg = String.format("could not get token for event %s because of %s",
                           event.toString(), tokenResponse.cause());
                       LOG.error(errorMsg);
                       message.fail(500, errorMsg);
                   } else {
                       AccessToken token = tokenResponse.result();
                       String accessToken = token.principal().getString("access_token");
                       LOG.info(String.format("obtained access token %s for API URL %s", accessToken, event.apiUrl));
                       getShopInfo(accessToken, event.apiUrl).setHandler(shopInfo -> {
                           if (shopInfo.failed()) {
                               String errorMsg = String.format("could not get shop info for event %s because of %s",
                                   event.toString(), shopInfo.cause());
                               LOG.error(errorMsg);
                               message.fail(500, errorMsg);
                           } else {
                               Future<JsonObject> installationCompleted = createInstallation(accessToken,
                                   shopInfo.result(), event);
                               installationCompleted.setHandler(installationResult -> {
                                   if (installationResult.failed()) {
                                       String errorMsg = String.format(
                                           "could not create installation for event %s because of %s",
                                           event.toString(), installationResult.cause());
                                       LOG.error(errorMsg);
                                       message.fail(500, errorMsg);
                                   } else {
                                       message.reply(installationResult.result());
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       });
                   }
               });
           }
       };
   };
   ```
3. Callback hell also in tests: e.g. [`AppInstallationVerticleTest::_testAppInstallationOauthDance()`](https://github.com/thokari/epages-app-kickstart/blob/master/src/test/java/de/thokari/epages/app/AppInstallationVerticleTest.java#L113-L168)

   ```
   @Test
   public void testAppInstallationOauthDance(TestContext context) {
       Async async = context.async();


       // GIVEN


       CompositeFuture.all(apiMockStarted, databasePrepared).setHandler(started -> {
           if (started.failed()) {
               started.cause().printStackTrace();
               context.fail();
               async.complete();
           }


           vertx.deployVerticle(AppInstallationVerticle.class.getName(), deploymentOpts, deployed -> {
               if (deployed.failed()) {
                   deployed.cause().printStackTrace();
                   context.fail();
                   async.complete();
               }


               // WHEN


               vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>send(
                   AppInstallationVerticle.EVENT_BUS_ADDRESS,
                   installationEvent.toJsonObject(),
                   response -> {


                       // THEN
                       context.assertTrue(response.succeeded(),
                           response.cause() != null ? response.cause().getMessage() : null);
                       context.assertEquals(null, response.result().body());


                       dbClient.getConnection(connected -> {
                           if (connected.failed()) {
                               connected.cause().printStackTrace();
                               context.fail();
                               async.complete();
                           }
                           connected.result().query(
                               String.format("SELECT access_token FROM installations WHERE api_url = '%s'",
                                   installationEvent.apiUrl),
                               result -> {
                                   if (result.failed()) {
                                       result.cause().printStackTrace();
                                       context.fail();
                                   }
                                   context.assertEquals(tokenResponse.getString("access_token"),
                                       result.result().getResults().get(0).getValue(0));
                                   context.assertEquals(1, result.result().getNumRows());
                                   async.complete();
                               });
                       });
                   });
           });
       });
       async.awaitSuccess(2000);
   }
   ```

Comment: The code formatting is unfortunately not always working for big blocks... Can we still move this to discussion?

Comment: @ThomasHirsch That happens because the automatic formatter tool doesn not like `code` in between lists. You could negate this by adding a line in between with `---`

Comment: Allright, thank you very much for correcting it!

Comment: @Ludisposed Is there an option to rename question in order to gain some attention? I'd change the title to "Java Microservice Development" or something...

Comment: @ThomasHirsch The best way would be to put up a bounty, however I see you have not enough reputation for that. Sometimes your just unlucky. These comments will bump it to the active page though

Comment: @Ludisposed: Code in between lists is okay, but it requires more indentation (8 spaces instead of 4). I've just fixed that here.

Answer (score 2):

1. No ORM - You don't want to use any ORM framework and that is fine. However you have to prevent [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to say the least. If your program takes client parameters as-is and/or you don't use `PreparedStatements`, then the application is vulnerable. I was in a similar situation: using Vertx and dislike ORMs.

   That is why I've chosen [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) for database communication. jOOQ's principle is 'schema first' and 'embrace SQL', so you take your (existing) database-schema, run the jOOQ code-generator and it will create DAOs, POJOs and the whole schema as Java Objects, so you can perform typesafe SQL. When I used it, I was missing some convenience features to execute jOOQ queries on a Vertx thread or transforming POJOs into `JsonObjects`. That is where I started writing [vertx-jooq](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq), which does all this. Maybe you want to give it a try.
2. Mixing future with callbacks - First thing to mention: a vertx `Future<T>` extends `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>`. So all code that takes a `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>` as an argument (e.g. `someMethod(Handler<AsyncResult<T>> handler)`) can be used as follows:

   ```
   Future<T> future = Future.future();
   someMethod(future);
   ```

   Next step is to use composition or mapping instead of the `setHandler`-method to act on the `Future`s result.

   Instead of writing:

   ```
   requestOAuth2Token(credentials, event.code, event.returnUrl).setHandler(h->
   {
       if(h.succeeded()) 
           /* do something */ 
       else 
           /* handle error*/
   });
   ```

   you would write:

   ```
   requestOAuth2Token(credentials, event.code, event.returnUrl).compose(token -> 
   {
       String accessToken = token.principal().getString("access_token");
       LOG.info(String.format("obtained access token %s for API URL %s", accessToken, event.apiUrl));
       return getShopInfo(accessToken, event.apiUrl).compose(shopInfo ->
           createInstallation(accessToken,shopInfo, event);
       );
   });
   ```

   and only in the final step you can invoke `setHandler` to act on the result to send a response on success / failure. I also suggest to check the [`Future`-API](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html).
3. See 2.

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) kudos for pointing out the necessity to address security concerns when avoiding tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated!
Regarding SQL injection, I am generally aware of the problem, and I thought I alleviated that by using the parameterised queries API, i.e. passing a string `(?, ?, ?)`, and the parameters separately.

Comment: @infinikli Just to clarify this, so in order to get the else branch in your example above, I'd need to call `otherwise()` on the first future? I think I tried that combination but somehow could not make it pass the tests...

Comment: Correct, either `otherwise()` or `recover()`. The former in case your function returns just a value (or `null`), the latter if your function returns a `Future`.